# Unir varias hojas de Excel en un sólo dataframe con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, vscode

Tengo un archivo de excel con hojas por día y cada una de ellas tiene las siguientes columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al utilizar

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(ruta_archivo + nombre_archivo,sheet_name=None),ignore_index=True)
```

en lugar de juntar todas las hojas en algunos casos las agrega como columnas, ya que a pesar de ser las mismas columnas no tienen exactamente los mismos nombres.

No sé que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar hojas distintas de excel debes usar el argumento sheet_name del metodo to_excel() de pandas en conjunto a la clase ExcelWriter de pandas.

Te dejo el ejemplo que encontre en internet, simplemente reemplaza el nombre de variables y strings para que se ajuste a tu codigo ya que no entregaste tu codigo en el problema no puedo dar una solucion exacta. Tambien adjunto el origen de la oslcuion, debiste googlearla primero porque es inmediato el resultado.

#### EJEMPLO

```
import pandas as pd

### CARGAR ARCHIVO EXCEL DE NOMBRE ARCHIVO.XLSX
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('archivo.xlsx')

### GUARDAR EL DATAFRAME planets en la hoja nombrada planets del excel contenido en ### writer

### las hojas se crean si no existe, se sobre escribren si existen
### esto es extensible a la x cantidad de dataframes que tengas 
planets.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="planets", index=False)
tips.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="tips", index=False)


writer.save()
writer.close()
```

#### links

youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtvaiyyC7zk&ab_channel=cctmexico

foro
https://www.analyticslane.com/2020/07/06/guardar-diferentes-hojas-excel-con-python/

recuerda primero buscar la informacion antes de postear problemas, y adjuntar el codigo y archivos cuando hagas una.